# Weird behavior of Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have following two project:

1. Class library project created using "Class Library (.Net Core)" template in Visual Studio 2015. (using .Net Core 1.6 framework)
2. Same Class library project created using "Class Library (.Net Core)" template in Visual Studio 2017 RC. (using .Net Core 1.6 framework)

Both projects have same class called DataAccess defined as below:

```
using System;
namespace WebApp.DataAccess
{
   public class DataAccess
   {
   }
}
```

Neither library projects have anything more than above class file nor class has anything more than shown above.
Now when I compile class library project in Visual Studio 2015 it compiles without any errors however in Visual Studio 2017 RC I am getting compile time error `"The namespace 'WebApp.DataAccess' already contains a definition for 'DataAccess'`. I am sure that "DataAccess" is not defined anywhere else in Visual Studio 2017 class library as library has only one class file i.e. DataAccess. Can someone please throw some light on whats wrong with Visual Studio 2017 project?

Comment: Show clearly the folder view of your VS2017 RC project please. If there is any .cs file in that folder (and sub folders), it can cause duplicate classes. The new MSBuild scheme is very sensitive.